# how to display max and min number from database in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

how to display max and min number in cakephp controller part .

```
$rs = $this->Item->find('all' , array ('fields' => array('Max(Item.no) as no')));
```

I want max number of Item table .

I need to add some rand number to that and save it in new row .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below query

```
$rs = $this->Item->find('all' , array ('fields' => array('Max(Item.no) as no')));
```

This query will return max number in below format

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [no] => 27
        )

)

$max = $rs[0]['no'];
```

Comment: error : Undefined index: no . how to resolve this issue

Comment: try to print your array pr($rs); this will show the result.Please make sure debug is set to 2

Comment: how ?? I am fresher for this cake php will u explain me .

Comment: just go to app folder -> config folder -> core.php (open this file) now search for debug and make zero to two like this Configure::write('debug',2);

Comment: Notice (8): Undefined index: no [APP\Controller\ItemController.php, line 28]; Still its showing error

Comment: try this $rs = $this->Item->find('first' , array ('fields' => array('Max(Item.no)'))); pr($rs); It gives this error when trying to access the record that does not exists

Comment: Its displaying first no .. actually i entered 2 numbers 12 and 100 . but its displaying 12 .. But the actual op is 100    .

Answer (score 0):

In cakephp 4 controller do this. it's okay for me

```
$conditions = array('Items.id'=> 4, .....);
$query = $this->Ite;s->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions,));
$maxItem  = $query->select(['maxItem' => $query->func()->max('price')])->first();
```